# Connection string property has not be initialized

Tags: c#, ado.net

When I add a Car in my application I get

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

I have the problem of ConnectionString property.  I check similar question of mine but I found nothing helpfulness.

I use a class connection named dbConnection.cs:

```
class dbConnection
{      
  //Connection to database 
  private string con = "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MLQ7024; Integrated Security=TRUE".ToString();

  public string Con
  {
    get
    {
      return con;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code of my button

```
private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
  {
    DataTable dtCar = new DataTable();
    BindingSource Car_bs = new BindingSource();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Add_Car", con))
    {                  
      try
      {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //......
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        dtCar.Clear();
        da.Fill(dtCar);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\t" + ex.Source);
      }
    }
  }

  refreshCar();            
}
```

This is the code of an another button working well without error

```
private void btnAddPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
  {
    DataTable dtPayment = new DataTable();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Add_Paiements", con))
    {
      try
      {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_paiement", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtBoxPaymentId.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@montant", SqlDbType.SmallMoney).Value = txtBoxAmount.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_Location", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cmbpaymentLesaseId.Text;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtBoxStatusPayment.Text;


         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         dtPayment.Clear();
         da.Fill(dtPayment);

         btnAddLease.Hide();
         refreshPayments();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\t" + ex.Source);
       }
     }
   }
   btnAddPayment.Hide();
 }
```

Comment: Please provide info about dc.Con.

Comment: so what is `dc.Con`?  For that matter, what is `dc`?  Is it some static class with your connection information?  Is it a non-static class?

Comment: dc is the connection?? did you add the connection string to it?

Comment: try to DEBUG. what is the value of dc.Con at runtime?

Comment: dbConnection dc = new dbConnection();  I initialize  ay the start of the form

Comment: value of dc.Con =Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MLQ7024; Integrated Security=TRUE

Comment: You're going to need to OPEN that connection at some point

Comment: @jim, the code he shows does open the connection.

Comment: Yes the connection open, and the add of my car work , but the message of string connection ....

Comment: I will show you a working button on the same logic in the same form...

Comment: @MikeC. it's ok to open it after you've added it to the command? I did not know that, and I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @jim Why not? What's the difference?

Comment: They have no diffence...

Comment: @ Frank - When you step through the code @ what line does it throw the error?

Comment: Its weird the because they do the try whitout error but catch: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't showing where you have initialized your `dbConnection` class.  Changing it all to static will probably help, I'm guessing:

```
static class dbConnection
{      
  //Connection to database 
  private static string con = "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MLQ7024; Integrated Security=TRUE"

  public static string Con
  {
    get
    {
      return con;
    }
  }
}
```

If your `dbConnection` class worked in one method but not the other, chances are you had it initialized in one and not the other.  Unless you have to deal with different database connections, using a static class for your database connections is probably the best route.

Then you change your calling method like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnection.Con))
{
  // blah-blah
}
```

Comment: He said he initialized it at the start of the form in the comment section.

Comment: @KreepN He's claiming that, but the error message is pretty clear cut that it didn't happen for that second method.

Comment: Yea, Id agree with your suggestion, but it looks as though he's using a tableadapter in his code to fill his datatable. I was curious as to if the tableadapter (which has a connection string) was possibly the cause of the error. As the second snippet doesn't use a TA.

Comment: dbConnection dc = new dbConnection(); error = Error 1 Cannot declare a variable of static type

Comment: Remove the declaration and use: 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnection.Con))

Comment: @FrankSharp - You mention that it completes the try portion. Do me a favor and step through the code, right after you execute the line: da.Fill(dtCar); does it go to the catch portion or does it step to the next line which is a closing bracket?

Comment: @FrankSharp I updated post with the example.  KreepN commented, too.

Comment: I don't doubt you are getting the same error, but we need to know what line is causing the error. Visual studio will go straight to the catch portion when it encounters an error which is how you can step through the code and pinpoint what line is throwing the exception.

Comment: you can add me in a chat please

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dc` is your connection, then it has to be initialized with a connection string. Maybe - if it's a class - you have to set some properties, like database path, etc.

Comment: Yes it's a class, I add this class in the code of my question

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection Con= New SQLConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MLQ7024; Integrated Security=TRUE");
```